# No module named 'plotly.express' whil it is installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, plotly-dash

I try to run some dash programs. The modules are installed but the application has problems importing `plotly.express`, the error being: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly.express'. This is strange as I can import it without problems in python and ipython. The problem seems to be importing plotly.express in an ide: in both spyder and vscode plotly.express refuses to be imported. Plotly by the way is imported without problems.

I created complete new environments, tried jupyter-dash instead of dash, no help. Is there any way of running a dash app that import plotly.express from vscode or spyder?

Comment: Have you tried running the application through a terminal, not an IDE-based terminal?

Comment: I did run it from python and ipython in a terminal and it worked. It seems ot be an IDE thing.

Comment: I can speak for VSCode, if you run it using the python extension (with the green play button), make sure you are in the python environment that have installed it in by checking the python interpreter in the blue bottom bar. Otherwise, if you run it through the terminal on VSCode, just make sure you are in the python venv you have installed it it and run ```python YOUR_APP.py```